# iOS SwiftUI - Reset VideoPlayer to beginning of video

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I can't seem to stop video, only pause, but that leads to the video starting where it was paused, instead of starting over again as I'd like it to on the next time a user plays the video.

```
VStack {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                player.pause()
            }
    }
```

How am I able to stop the video on disappear, so that it resets each time it plays?

Comment: Unfortunately no, in SwiftUI it appears player.currentTime is a function, and cannot be passed an argument. ```player.currentTime(0)``` does not work, nor do the examples offered in the answers in that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.onDisappear {                        
  player.pause()
  player.seek(to: .zero)
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385953-seek